# How to Simulate the performance, throughput, end2end delay, average of consumed energy and PDR for routing protocols in WSN?

Tags: ns2, opnet

i have an issue with my study task, and in need to Simulate the performance, throughput, end2end delay, average of consumed energy and PDR for EAR (Energy
Aware Routing protocol) , MQOSR and SR-MQOSR routing protocols in wireless sensor network WSN.
Witch simulator should i use NS2 or Opnet. i tried to use NS2 but the source code for this protocols not available, any one have them?
Or this protocols included in Opnet to use them?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an open-source simulator called ONE simulator that may support what you are looking for.

Check [this](https://www.mdpi.com/2224-2708/5/4/18/htm#B7-jsan-05-00018) for more information.